# What is the dimension for the following basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my lecture notes, my professor says the following statement.

> Find a basis for the subspace $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ defined by $2x_1 −x_2 +2x_3+4x_4=0$

He goes on to say that:

"We know $\dim(W) = 3$, so we just need $3$ linearly independent vectors in $W$."

My question is why? Since this is in the vector space of $\mathbb{R}^4$, shouldn't the basis dimensions also be $4$?

Comment: Since we have one equation in the four variables, namely once we fix $x_1$, $x_3$, and $x_4$, we determine $x_2$. So there are only 3 degrees of freedom, i.e. the dimension is 3.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, each equation that helps define a subspace decreases the dimension by $1$, hence the $3$ here (to be precise, I should say *independent* equations. For example, $\{(x, y): x = y {\rm\ and\ }2x = 2y\}$ only counts as having one independent equation).

Comment: $W$ is a 3-dimensional subspace of $R^4$. Just as $\{(x,y)\in R^2: x+y=0\}$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $R^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all vectors of $W$ are solutions of the given equation, then you can find that $x_2=2x_1+2x_3+4x_4$, thus the form of solution is $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\2x_1+2x_3+4x_4\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}=x_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+x_3\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+x_4\begin{pmatrix}0\\4\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$i.e $\displaystyle W=\text{Sp}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\4\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$, thus $\dim(W)=3$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$W$ is the kernel of the linear map $T: (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T\mapsto 2x_1-x_2+2x_3+4x_4$. The image of this map is clearly one-dimensional, so by the Rank-Nullity theorem, $\dim W=4-1=3$.